# How do I determine the original aspect ratio of an imported image?

Tags: graphics, import

Say I import a TIFF, JPEG, or PDF image.  How can I quickly determine the original aspect ratio of the image so that I can properly scale its size?  I have thus far been unable to find an answer looking through the manual.

Comment: `ImageAspectRatio` or `ImageDimensions` should do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ImageDimensions` will give you the pixel dimensions of an imported image, from which can calculate the aspect ratio:

```
img = Import["http://www.eschertile.com/pic/ss-2.jpg"];
```

[image]

```
ImageDimensions[img]
```

> ```
> {858, 705}
> ```

Comment: And `ImageAspectRatio` in versions 8 and 9... :)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to know the aspect ration of the image without importing the image itself, you can use "ImageSize" as last parameter to `Import`

```
N[Divide @@ Reverse@
  Import["http://www.eschertile.com/pic/ss-2.jpg", "ImageSize"]]
```

which gives the same value of `0.821678` as

```
ImageAspectRatio[Import["http://www.eschertile.com/pic/ss-2.jpg"]] // N
```